# class declaration in C++

Tags: c++, dllimport, dllexport

I have a Class :
`class RTC_EXPORT PeerConnectionInterface : public rtc::RefCountInterface { ... };`

RTC_EXPORT is defined as

```
#ifndef RTC_BASE_SYSTEM_RTC_EXPORT_H_
#define RTC_BASE_SYSTEM_RTC_EXPORT_H_

// RTC_EXPORT is used to mark symbols as exported or imported when WebRTC is
// built or used as a shared library.
// When WebRTC is built as a static library the RTC_EXPORT macro expands to
// nothing.

#ifdef WEBRTC_ENABLE_SYMBOL_EXPORT
#ifdef WEBRTC_WIN

#ifdef WEBRTC_LIBRARY_IMPL
#define RTC_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)  
#else
#define RTC_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#else  // WEBRTC_WIN

#if __has_attribute(visibility) && defined(WEBRTC_LIBRARY_IMPL)
#define RTC_EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#endif

#endif  // WEBRTC_WIN

#endif  // WEBRTC_ENABLE_SYMBOL_EXPORT

#ifndef RTC_EXPORT
#define RTC_EXPORT
#endif

#endif  // RTC_BASE_SYSTEM_RTC_EXPORT_H_
```

What does RTC_EXPORT in `class RTC_EXPORT PeerConnectionInterface :public rtc::RefCountInterface {...};` do?

Usually we define classes in c++ as `class Myclass{...}`. What does the additional MACRO do in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The macros is defined in your snippet:

```cpp
#ifdef WEBRTC_LIBRARY_IMPL
#define RTC_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)  
#else
#define RTC_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

That allows to use the same class declaration for both dynamic library and the caller code.

> The dllexport and dllimport storage-class attributes are
> Microsoft-specific extensions to the C and C++ languages. You can use
> them to export and import functions, data, and objects to or from a
> DLL.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/dllexport-dllimport?view=vs-2019

Comment: What is the difference between  class Myclass {...};   and class RTC_EXPORT Myclass {...} ? What is the purpose of addition of a macro in a class declaration?

Comment: The difference is that it is not you "who has a class", but someone else who designed a library. This symbol has to be exported from this library to make possible for you to use something that is defined outside of your module. Whenever you design your own class and don't plan to extract it to the library, `class MyClass {};` would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Dmitry's answer I want to add some practical tools to examine the influence of `__declspec()`. Consider the following source file:

```
// library.cpp
__declspec(dllexport) int func(int x) { return 2 * x; }
```

Start a native tools command prompt from your Visual Studio installation inside your start
menu. There you can compile and link `library.cpp` to a DLL with the following commands:

```
> cd <Directory containing library.cpp>
> cl /c library.cpp
> link library.obj /DLL /NOENTRY
```

There should be a freshly created `library.dll` next to `library.cpp`. The following command examines the exported symbols:

```
> dumpbin /EXPORTS library.dll
```

You should see something along the following lines:

```
Dump of file library.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for library.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    FFFFFFFF time date stamp
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           1 number of functions
           1 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00001000 ?func@@YAHH@Z
```

As you can see, `library.dll` exports a function `?func@@YAHH@Z`, that's the way C++ names the function `func` internally. If you omit `__declspec(dllexport)`, you won't see this export. Likewise, only a class annotated with `__declspec(dllexport)` will export all of its member functions.

**Summary:** In order to export a function from a DLL you have to annotate it with `__declspec(dllexport)`.

Now, the usual approach for exporting classes from a DLL is to define such a `#ifdef` switch in your header:

```
// header.h
#pragma once

#ifdef BUILD_LIBRARY
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

EXPORT int func(int x);
```

Inside the sources of the library you define this magic macro `BUILD_LIBRARY`:

```
// library.cpp
#define BUILD_LIBRARY
#include "header.h"

int func(int x) { return 2 * x; }
```

Thus the function will be exported from your library. Consumers of your DLL will include `header.h` but shall not define `BUILD_LIBRARY`:

```
#include "header.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << func(10) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Since this compilation unit doesn't define `BUILD_LIBRARY` the `EXPORT` macro equals to `__declspec(dllimport)`.